# Function to display single returned value from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure which takes no parameters. It goes through the database to find the most commonly recorded screen resolution and outputs said resolution as the sole return value.

The stored procedure takes two columns, `ScreenWidth` and `ScreenHeight` (both `int`) and concatenates them with an `x` in between to return a single text value for the screen resolution

Here's the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspRetMostCommonScreenRes]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT TOP 1 
        CAST(ScreenWidth as nvarchar(MAX)) + 'x' +
        CAST(ScreenHeight as nvarchar(MAX)) AS Resolutions
    FROM 
        BrowserInfoes
    GROUP BY 
        CAST(ScreenWidth as nvarchar(MAX)) + 'x' + CAST(ScreenHeight as nvarchar(MAX))
    ORDER BY 
        COUNT(*) DESC   
END
```

This executes absolutely fine and returns the value `1600x1024`

I then want to create some code in C# which will get this sole value and store it into a string value.

The only experience I have with interfacing between C# and SQL Server is inputting data through Entity Framework, so I have no knowledge on how I'd go about this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudocode for what you are trying to do is the following

```
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(....here the connection string ....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspRetMostCommonScreenRes", cnn))
{
    cnn.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

This code requires a [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/) that allows your C# program to connect to your database.
Then you define an [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) pointing to your stored procedure and to your connection
Finally you could open the connection, flag the commandtext as a StoredProcedure name and execute the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The using statement takes care to close and dispose the connection and the command

Comment: Thanks for the answer Steve, what assembly references would I need to add for this to work?

Comment: None, you need just the `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Trying to implement it but it is throwing quite a few errors. "cmd" and "commandtype" do not exist in the current context. Also, will the connection string of "./SQLExpress" work for my local DB?

Comment: Missing a close parenthesis on the using of SqlCommand. Fixed now. The connection string depends on the technology used. LocalDB has a particular connection string, while a local Sql Express needs also the database name. The link provided to the connectionstrings.com has plenty of use cases to look for

Comment: Almost working now, connection string is sorted, just getting "CommandType does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Didn't have System.Data, got it now.

Comment: Just a small follow up: Is it possible to execute another stored procedure within the same block of code (for example, uspLeastCommonScreenRes) or do I have to repeat the original block of code twice?

Comment: You have to change the CommandText and reexecute ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNonQuery or ExecuteReader depending on what this second procedure does. It is also possible that you need to add something to the parameters collection.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating the proc to return the two INT values as distinct values, which gives you the flexibility of having them separate or combining them into the "widthXheight" format, or both.

Returning the raw INT values will be much more efficient since you are losing performance on the GROUP BY that has to be done over the concatenated values.

Sticking with the INT values instead of concatenating also allows for an index created on (ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight) to be used for the GROUP BY operation, which will speed up the query even more.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspRetMostCommonScreenRes]
(
  @Width INT OUTPUT,
  @Height INT OUTPUT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT TOP 1 @Width = ScreenWidth,
             @Height = ScreenHeight
FROM BrowserInfoes
GROUP BY ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

And here is how you use it:

```
int _Height = -1;
int _Width = -1;

SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection("connect string");
SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand("uspRetMostCommonScreenRes", _Connection);
_Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

_SqlParameter _WidthParam = new SqlParameter("@Width", SqlDbType.Int);
_WidthParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
_Command.Parameters.Add(_WidthParam);

_SqlParameter _HeightParam = new SqlParameter("@Height", SqlDbType.Int);
_HeightParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
_Command.Parameters.Add(_HeightParam);

try
{
  _Connection.Open();

  _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  _Width = (int)_WidthParam.Value;
  _Height = (int)_HeightParam.Value;
}
finally
{
  _Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks strutzky I'll definitely consider using that method if my current one doesn't work!

Comment: @Frayt no problem. I just added a note to my answer regarding performance. Depending on the size of the table (especially as the data volume grows), doing a GROUP BY on concatenated values will take a toll. Also, using the raw fields as I am showing allows you to add an index on `(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)` to make that GROUP BY even faster :).